# Why my programm prints wrong decimal number

Tags: c

I have given the 8 hex digits (as example):

```
long a0 = 00
long a1 = 2E
long a2 = E8
long a3 = A0
long a4 = 58
long a5 = 0F
long a6 = 37
long a7 = FF
```

and i want to print this in decimal.

So I have tried:

```
long long Decimal = (pow(16, 14) * a) + (pow(16, 12) * a1) + (pow(16, 10) * a2) + (pow(16, 8) * a3) + (pow(16, 6) * a4) + (pow(16, 4) * a5) + (pow(16, 2) * a6) + (pow(16, 0) * a7);
```

but i get a decimal number which isnt the right decimal. As for the example the decimal value is 13203624298493951 but i get 13203624298493952.

Thanks guys for helping

Comment: `pow` is a floating point function and will lose accuracy. You should use integer operations instead (and make sure to not overflow). Look into the `<<` operator. where `a << b` means a*(2^b)

Comment: Your confusing the notion of value and output format.    Just store the value in an `unsigned` type that is guaranteed to be 64-bit (or more) and print it with appropriate formatting.  For example `unsigned long long value = 0x002EE8A0580F37FF` and print it using an approrpriate format such as `printf("%llu\n", value)`.

Comment: @M.M: Re “`pow` is a floating point function and will lose accuracy.”: Actually, all of the `pow` calls in this case should return exactly correct results. The actual errors arise in the last additions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pow` uses floating-point arithmetic and returns a `double` result, which causes the rest of the arithmetic in your statement to use `double`. The `double` floating-point arithmetic in your C implementation does not have sufficient precision to represent the numbers you are working with exactly.

Instead of using `(pow(16, 14) * a0)`, use `(long long) a0 << 4*14`. This uses integer arithmetic, and the results will be exact as long as the values do not overflow the `long long` type.

Note that if the high bit of `a0` (considering it as an eight-bit number) might be set, meaning that the final result is intended to be a negative number, then `(long long) a0 << 4*14` will overflow a 64-bit `long long` type. You will need to write different code to handle the negative-number cases. If you want all results to be unsigned, not negative, use `unsigned long long` instead of `long long`.